# input simulate change doesn't work in enzyme with event object provided

Tags: redux-form, enzyme

I have a unit test written as:

```
it('shows validation message when predicate is violated', () => {
    const input = subject.find('input').at(0);   
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: " " } });      
    input.simulate('blur');
    expect(subject.find('[role="alert"]').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

which I get Expected value to equal: 1, Received: 0.

The input validation picks up empty value and returns an error message. I have tested that `subject.find('[role="alert"]')` will catch the error message if it presents, and `input.props().value` also gives empty string. So I suspect `simulate('click')` didn't work. I have gone through many, many related issues but didn't find my answer, hope someone could help!

My input element is simple:

```
<Field
  name="customerFirstName"
  label = "First name"
  type="text"
  component={inputField}
  validate={required}
/>


const inputField = props => {
    const { input, label, type, meta: { touched, error }} = props;

    return (
        <FormGroup>
            <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            { touched && error && <span>{error}</span> }
        </FormGroup>
    )
}
```

Validation is:

```
export const required = value => {
    if (value) { value = value.trim() };
    return value ? undefined : ErrorMessage('This field is required')
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code from the input element, i.e. how it does the validation?
I suspect that there is a problem with your event, since event.target should be the input element (not just some object), but you cannot do that in your test since you want to change "value".

Comment: Hi @DavidTanzer thanks for reply. I have added more info there. Hmm, I pass in the event as `{ target: { value: " " } }`. We have another similar form and I did kinda the same thing...didn't see what's special about this one. Also the examples on official doc suggest the same (at bottom): http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html#-simulate-event-mock-self

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are right, then it's definitely not what I had expected.

Comment: @DavidTanzer Still my big thanks :) I suspect the reason is that I didn't config the redux store properly for the tests, so the validator of redux form doesn't take efforts. Working on it...

Comment: all right! Don't forget to answer your own question, once you solved the problem :) So that others can still learn from it.